# DevTools automatic call stack listing to console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, edge-devtools

Is there a way in Edge or Chrome DevTools to the call stack to spool to the console?

If not every call, can it at least show me any async calls as they happen? Is there a way to automatically break on async invocation?

I am trying to diagnose infinite loops and the call stack the Source tab displays clearly does not tell the whole story (or it would be millions of lines long even after a couple seconds of running). If I could get it to produce a log of calls maybe I could find where it's circular.

I cannot manually instrument. The code is compiled (Svelte) and so complex I can't get through a single iteration after stepping line-by-line for 20 minutes non-stop. There has to be something better than hitting F11 constantly for an hour...